# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 syncing problem with multiple SQLSERVERCe database instances

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 to sync Database instances. I have a query related to the following points:

1. Can I sync multiple SQLSERVERCe database instances with SQLSERVER instance at a time together?
2. Also if I have deleted a record using one on the SQLSERVERCe database instance and after that another one SQLSERVERCe database instance is updateing the same record.. how to deal with this scenario... ? what should be the record entry at SQLSERVER database instance?
3. Is there any any parent child relationship between SQLSERVER database instance and SQLSERVERCe database instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which provider are you using? SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider?

Assuming its the above:

1. Yes. If you however define one scope only, then the Sql Ce clients apps synching will have contention on the same scope_info row containing the sync knowledge. and they will also have contention the tables/rows being synched.
2. You'll get a conflict. When the second client syncs, there is no record to update anymore and Sync Framework will raise a conflict (most likely ClientUpdateServerDelete)
3. If you used the providers above, there is no parent child relationship. the above providers work in a peer-to-peer fashion. you can even sync Sql Ce to Sql Ce.

Comment: thanx JuneT for the answer. Yes I am using  SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider.                                   so how to solve the particular problem related to #2. How could I stop such type of transaction to occur?

Comment: depends how do you want to handle the conflict. do you restore the record from client 2? or if the previous delete should prevail, then you simply ignore the conflict on the upload and on download make sure the delete gets applied on client 2.

Comment: thanx. so any tutorial on this from where I can handle these type of conficts.